# Realm Grinder - Titan challenge 4

Tags: achievements, realm-grinder

In Realm Grinder, I'm not sure how to achieve Titan Challenge 4.

It states:

> Hit Halls of Legends with Lightning Strike 2 times in a row without using any researches. You must have at least 1 of each building

But I don't see how I could achieve this, unless being very lucky or with an extreme amount of time ahead of me. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up doing was set Lightning Strike to autocast and leave it running for the day.

Just for the "fun" I went ahead and looked up how many spells I'd have to cast on [Realm Weather Service](http://dox4242.github.io/rws/index.html) before completing the challenge, it was a whooping 400 casts.